# Moving Average from data stream

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge

I wrote a code for one of the leetcode problems but I am not satisfied. I believe I could improve it. Here is my code:

```
class MovingAverage {

    Queue<Integer> myQueue;
    int size;

    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    public MovingAverage(int size) {
        myQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        this.size = size;

    }

    public double next(int val) {
        int sum = 0;

        if(myQueue.size() < size) {
            myQueue.add(val);
        } else {
            myQueue.remove(); // removes the head node
            myQueue.add(val);
        }

        for(Integer item : myQueue){
            sum += item;
        }

        return (double) sum / myQueue.size();
    }
}
```

Runtime: 58 ms
Memory 47.8 mb

Please I need your opinions and possible improvement ideas.

Comment: Please add a description of the challenge. There are a lot of leetcode problems.

Comment: (Please don't call a *piece of code* / a *sequence of statements* `a code` - that's [something else](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code).)

Answer (score 6):

- [Document your code. In the code.](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide)
  • what use is `MovingAverage`?
  • is `size` fixed for the lifetime of any given `MovingAverage` instance?
   I don't know even scrutinising the code: `size` is neither `final` nor `private`
  • what does `next(int value)` return?
- accumulate `int`s into `long`s - even the sum of *two* `int`s can overflow.
- program against `interface`s - and give yourself and others a chance to:
  define  `interface`s
- take advantage of work already done: keep the sum around and update it instead of computing it from scratch
- don't repeat yourself (DRY): there's `myQueue.add(val);` in both branches of your conditional statement

Assuming `size` fixed:

```
 /** provide one running summary about
 *  <code>int</code> values specified one by one. */
interface RunningIntStatistics {
    /** Returns the next summary value
     *  given the additional input <code>value</code>.*/
    double next(int value);
}

/** moving average over the last up to <code>size</code> 
 * <code>int</code> values specified one by one.
 * <code>size</code> is specified for instantiation.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MovingAverage extends java.util.ArrayDeque<Integer>
implements RunningIntStatistics {
    final int size;
    long sum;

    /** Fixes <code>size</code>. */
    public MovingAverage(int size) {
        super(size);
        this.size = size;
    }

    public double next(int value) {
        // fine point: _if_ there are "extra" elements,
        // should their values get subtracted?
        while (size <= size())
            sum -= remove().longValue();

        sum += value;
        add(value);

        return (double) sum / size();
    }
}
```

(`MovingAverage.next()` "inherits" `RunningIntStatistics.next()`'s doc comment.)
The above is somewhat lazy:
one should use *inheritance* in cases of specialisation,
else *composition*.
Using [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#getAverage()) still required keeping account of values to account for.

Comment: If so inclined, one can open code a queue limited to `size` using an `int[]`.

Comment: The above is "The obvious" implementation. A nit-pickish one would keep `size-1` values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based only on the code, I have suggestions:

1. For the variable, I suggest that you mark them `private` to prevent exposure; especially the collections.

   ```java
      private Queue<Integer> myQueue;
      private int size;
   ```
2. I think the comment on the constructor is useless.
3. You can remove the type `java.util.LinkedList`  in the diamond operation, in the implementation section.

   ```java
   new LinkedList<>();
   ```

#### `MovingAverage#next` Method

1. I suggest you invert the logic of the condition, since you add in all cases.

   ```
   if (myQueue.size() >= size) {
      myQueue.remove(); // removes the head node
   }

   myQueue.add(val);
   ```
2. I suggest that you extract the calculus of the sum in a method.

   ```
       private int getSum() {
          int sum = 0;

          for (Integer item : myQueue) {
             sum += item;
          }

          return sum;
       }
   ```

#### Refactored code

```java
public class MovingAverage {
   private Queue<Integer> myQueue;
   private int size;

   public MovingAverage(int size) {
      myQueue = new LinkedList<>();
      this.size = size;
   }

   public double next(int val) {

      if (myQueue.size() >= size) {
         myQueue.remove(); // removes the head node
      }

      myQueue.add(val);

      return (double) getSum() / myQueue.size();
    }

    private int getSum() {
      int sum = 0;

      for (Integer item : myQueue) {
         sum += item;
      }

      return sum;
   }
}
```